# Alternating information between two textfiles into a third textfile via stringlists

Tags: text-files, delphi-7, tstringlist

I have 2 files with information that looks like this

```
File 1
Show1
Show2
Show3
Show4
Show5
File2
Advert1
Advert2
```

I want to merge these two files into a 3rd textfile so that the output looks like this

```
Show1
Advert1
Show2
Advert2
Show3
Advert1
Show4
Advert2
Show5
```

The amount of information can vary, but file two will never have more lines than file 1

I have tried putting the information of the two text files into two different string lists and then reading them alternatively into a third string list via the indexes, I have tried hopping the information across different textiles and string lists and even arrays, but no matter what I try I always end up with an error, most often a list index error...

My latest attempt at this looks like this

```
For k := 0 to StringlistAdvert.Count - 1 do
 Begin
     StringListFinal.Add(StringlistShow[k]);
     StringListFinal.Add(StringListAdvert[k]);
     StringlistAdvert.Delete(k)
 End;
```

I realise that this was a stupid idea as I'm deleting the items in the string list which I later would have to use in the loop again. My other attempts were not much better

This is a relatively simple program compared to others I have coded before yet the solution to this keeps eluding me, it is for a school project so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `StringListAdvert[k mod StringListAdvert.Count]`

Comment: The item of the result is always from the first list?